# Checksum of a set of real numbers

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of real numbers $a_i \in (-r, r)$ which can be represented as the tuple $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ where $n \in (5,10)$. I am searching for an algorithm to generate a checksum so that I can verify that none of the $a_i$'s have changed. The arithmetric operators I have available are addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. The algorithm must ensure that all computed values are in the range $(-r, r)$.

The algorithms I have found are for detecting transmission errors of binary numbers or typing errors of e.g. social security numbers.

Comment: Do the numbers have to remain *exactly* the same, or is there room for error? Also, about how big is $n$?

Comment: They don't have to remain exactly the same. I would need 4 desimal places. So it is possible to multiply the $a_i$'s with 10000 and work with integers (as long they don't overflow). Overflow can be handled by defining a valid range for the $a_i$'s. $n \in (5,10)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the algorithms like check digit algorithms can be adapted to be used here. For example you can compute

$$\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{4}+\frac{a_3}{8}+...+\frac{a_n}{2^n}.$$

Depending on how you define exponentials, this may or may not be within your constraints because powers of two can just be stored or computed as repeated multiplication. Also if your list is too long you may run into underflow. This method should keep you within your interval though. An easy variant is

$$\frac{a_1}{1}+\frac{a_2}{2}+\frac{a_3}{3}+...+\frac{a_n}{n}$$ and again if your numbers are evenly distributed around zero then this should stay inside your interval but in case it doesn't you can alternatively add and subtract.

Things like an idea of what $r$ is (how large or small is it), how many numbers in a typical list, if you are worried about overflow/underflow, are you using exact arithmetic or floating point stuff, do you want just error detection or do you want error correction as well, what kind of numbers are $a_n$ like are they all integers, unit fractions, rational numbers, and do you want to detect just change in magnitude of a number or a change in position as well like if two elements get swapped (i.e. is $\{1,2,3\}$ the same as $\{1,3,2\}$ or is it considered an "error" for you?) are all things to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The numbers $a_i$ are floats. I want to detect whether any onf the $a_i$'s change in magnitude and if any element is swapped. I only want error detection. $n$ is less than 10.

Comment: Your proposal isn't generally correct. Given ${a_1, a_2}$, the checksum is $C = \frac{a_1}{2} + \frac{a_2}{4}$. Then the tuples $\{a'_1, 4C-2a'_1\}$ will have the same checksums. But all checksum algorithms have a given probability for that different input will give the same checksum. It's only a matter getting the probability low enough. Your algorithm would, as far as I can see, detect if one of the $a_i$'s change in magnitude or if their order is changed.

Comment: I know it isn't. This was meant to be the best algorithm out there, just something quick to get you started. You could probably take some other schemes and modify them to work for you with the probability being small enough.